# Generating the tableview in this format Category/subcategoy/subcategory

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having a requirement as using Tableview i have to give categories & in every category there is a subcategory and in every subcategory there is another subcategory list will be there.But every subcategory wont have subcategories that is not mandetory but few subcategory has subcategories. In this format in need to display my tableview..

For Example:

```
ROW 1
  SubDetails 1
    SubSubDetails 11
    SubSubDetails 12
    SubSubDetails 13
  SubDetails 2
  SubDetails 3
ROW 2
  SubDetails 1
    SubSubDetails 11
    SubSubDetails 12
    SubSubDetails 13
  SubDetails 2
    SubSubDetails 21
    SubSubDetails 22
    SubSubDetails 23
  SubDetails 3
    SubSubDetails 31
    SubSubDetails 32
    SubSubDetails 33
```

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Comment: number of subsubdetails are different for row?

Comment: In every subcategory will not have subcategory

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UItableViewCell. In that you can create views depending on data. Also in heightForRowAtIndexPath: calculate height from data. So everything will be dynamic depending on number of subcategories.